# Fail to download more than 2GB file (with copy process) in Express.js (Node.js)

Tags: file, express, copy, limit

## 1.Scenario

Click download => child_process.execSync(CopyFiles) => zip file => return res.send('ok'). 
But the problem is if the file to be zipped is big, it says failed to download.

I setup timeout and unlimit size in nginx config and BodyParser(json+urlencode to extended:true & limit: 
5mb).

Do I have to change config more than now? It seems to work well in local and copy files and zip properly in prod server but it just says can't download. And if I force to open page, it loops infinitely same logic.

I am using nginx, ec2, nuxt, express.js.
It response fail to download, network Error.

```
#copy file
files.forEach(file=> {
    return execSync(`cp ${folder}/${name} ${path}/images`)
})

#make ctx
await files.forEach(file=>{
  const canvas = createCanvas(file.width, file.height)
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

  labels.forEach(label => {
    ctx.beginPath()
    label.points.forEach(point => ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y))
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.fill()
  })

  const stream = canvas.createJPEGStream()
  const out = fs.createWriteStream(destination)
  stream.pipe(out)
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    out.on("finish", resolve)
  })

#zip
  execSync(
    `cd ${DSPath}/.. ;zip -r ${issue.id}_${now}.zip ./${issue.id}_${now}`,
  )

#download and remove file
  return res.download(`${path}/../file_name.zip`, err =>
      execSync(`cd ${DSPath}/.. ;rm -rf ./${issue.id}_${now}.zip ./${issue.id}_${now}/`))
```

````
#nginx
   sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;
    send_timeout 1800;
    proxy_read_timeout 5000;
    proxy_send_timeout 5000;
    proxy_connect_timeout 5000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 5000;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;```


    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
````

Comment: Can you post some code where you are handling the request and sending the response? The pseudo-code is nice, but the real thing may aid in solving your issue. Also, are you using [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) to handle the file downloads, because `body-parser` doesn't handle `multipart-form`.

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev updated Thank you

Comment: i upload 1 image, then create canvas with updating ctx so the file size is big.
currently 250mb when it zipped.
when i test, i chagne code return res.download to return res.send("ok").
when i console.log after each logic, it shows logs properly but at the end not res.send.

Comment: small size of file works well.

Comment: Which browser are you trying this in?

Comment: Chrome browser only, to file download, i click <a href="url" download> </a>

Comment: Have you tried changing the nginx config like [this](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2779#issuecomment-150292358)

Comment: now i update my nginx config.
my config: proxy_max_temp_file_size 0
now i'll try to change 0 to 0m...

Comment: I would try breaking this out into just sending the file to the browser. Remove everything else, and see if you can get that to work. Even the nginx proxy. At least isolate the source of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I don' think download is problem.
Though I change to res.download to res.send('ok'), if file is big(i am guessing over 200mb or timeout somewhere) it still loops.

Comment: What does it loop?

Comment: if i put <a href="api_url" target="_blank">
everything api works well properly it copys, make canvas, zip. but not rseponse.
 then it loop. copy again make canvas, zip... loop

but if <a href="api_url" download> it sends fail to download - network error

Comment: because if <a href="" target="_blank">, i have new tab. it'll run till any response whatever 404, 500... but it keep runs without return res.send.
it just call api again idk why sad.

Comment: I'm not sure either. Have you tried another browser? What folder is it trying to download to on your machine from the browser? Can you change that? Your server code looks fine to me.